Will a Consumer's Gradle be able to perform Dependency Mediation on an Artifact whose Producer made use of `implementation` during its buildup?
Assume:
ArtifactC:1.0.0
   ├── ClassA 
   │      ├ (uses)─ ArtifactA:1.0.0
   │      └ (uses)─ ArtifactB:1.0.0
   └── ClassB 
          └ (uses)─ ArtifactB:1.0.0

If ArtifactD  which compiles with
build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation('io.github.org:artifactc:1.0.0')
}

Case 1:
Uses only ClassB of ArtifactC:

Will ArtifactA:1.0.0 be completely pruned out (from [compile & run]-time) of ArtifactD?

My guess is "yes, they'll be completely pruned out", since whatever happens at run-time depends 100% on the things written at compile-time.
Case 2:
Now... In the case that ArtifactD DOES use ArtifactC.ClassA
Now assume:
ArtifactE:1.0.0
   ├── ClassA 
   │      └ (uses)─ ArtifactA:1.0.5
   └── ClassB 
          └ (uses)─ ArtifactD:1.0.0


Will ArtifactE's Gradle build tool be able to perform Dependency Mediation between ArtifactA:1.0.5 and the version of ArtifactA (ArtifactA:1.0.0) that lies within ArtifactD:1.0.0 EVEN IF artifactD used implementation during buildup making ArtifactA not available during compile-time?

According to some sources the answer is yes... but if this is the case... then what is the use for api?
